# streaming copy from one s3 endpoint to another in Python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, streaming, boto3, endpoint

I have a variation of the theme of copying objects from one s3 endpoint to another.

- Since some of the objects are quite large (more than memory), it needs to be a streaming copy (so put_object is mostly out, as documented)
- I'm copying from one endpoint (provider) to another, so can't use a single-provider tool.
- I can't give permissions from one to another to use CopyObject
- I also need to rename the object on the fly using a static mapping (which I have)
- prefer not to download each and every file to disk to reupload, but will if that's the only option
- there's no direct path between src-endpoint and end-endpoint, so this script runs on intermediate linux host for copy/rename

I've tried a bunch of different things, including trying a variation of streaming from a web/rest download to an upload, but I keep ending up with 0 byte files on the destination. Here's the closest one that seems like it should work, but doesn't.

src_client and dst_client are s3 client sessions with appropriate working creds at 2 providers

```
import io
import boto3
data = io.BytesIO()
src_client.download_fileobj(args.SRCBUCKET, args.SRCKEY, data)
# print(data.getvalue()) shows correct data here
dst_client.upload_fileobj(data, args.DSTBUCKET, args.DSTKEY)
# at this point <data> object is closed descriptor
```

I have also tried this:

```
data = io.BytesIO()
src_client.download_fileobj(args.SRCBUCKET, args.SRCKEY, data)
# confirmed that data.getvalue() here has the right stuff
with data as chunk:
    dst_client.upload_fileobj(chunk, args.DSTBUCKET, args.DSTKEY)
```

In both cases, the resulting object looks like this:

2022-06-19 09:40:13          0 Methods.dat

Comment: Would something like [this script](https://gist.github.com/Q726kbXuN/a42265cdf24dd7e2632a5e57de8e8727) that uses multipart parts to transfer files from one account to another solve these issues?

Comment: yes, that looks like it would be a good way to get the job done.